# File not recognized in the given path

Tags: java, eclipse, file, file-io

```
String inXSL="src/main/resources/abc.xslt";
```

Here am trying to get the file from the path name and process it but the file is never getting recognized from the given path(JAVA).FYI,the system is MAC.

The file is located inside `src/main/resources` inside the project.

Please provide inputs on this.

Comment: If it is a maven project, you should be able to access the file using just the name provided it is present in src/main/resources directory.

Comment: Try changing `/` with `File.seperator`. Also be careful when placing the file. In the project root try putting it in `res/file.xslt`. The res folder should be long side your `src and bin` folders.

Comment: Show the code that accesses this file.

Comment: you also need to make sure that files are presents in the build/target.. maven/ant does not automatically copy all files.

Comment: Please provide some more context, are you doing new File(inXSL)? If so you could always do sysout("file:" + new File().getFilename());

Comment: Thanks to all your replies.The below answer worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your application is packaged and built, your file will be placed within the class path of your jar (or war) along with the other classes.  It should be loaded using a resource stream.  Here is some sample code that would print the contents of the file by loading it from the classpath.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    byte[] contents = new byte[1024];
    InputStream inStream = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.xslt");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inStream);

    int bytesRead=0;
    String strFileContents = null;
    try {
      while( (bytesRead = bis.read(contents)) != -1){
        strFileContents = new String(contents, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.print(strFileContents);
  }
}
```

The important line is:

```
InputStream inStream = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.xslt");
```

Depending on your usage, the input stream would be passed into whatever API you are using.

Comment: This answer was relly helpful and it worked.Thank you so much.Now i understand it.